# What's wrong with this binary representation of a 1-bit monochrome B&W bmp image?

Tags: c, image, image-processing, bmp

I've written an ANSI C code to construct a simple monochrome BMP image (black and white only) and each pixel is represented with 1 bit.

the number of image pixels is 16*16 (32 byte) and I chose this size to avoid padding as the number of bytes divisible by 4 then I filled all the 32 bytes with 0xff to show a white image.

This is binary output on my Ubuntu terminal

```
00000000  42 4d 5e 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 3e 00 00 00 28 00  |BM^.......>...(.|
00000010  00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00  00 00 01 00 01 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ff 00 ff ff  |................|
00000040  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
0000005e
```

My code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

struct bmpHeader{

    unsigned char Signature[2];
    unsigned char FileSize[4];
    unsigned char reserved[4];
    unsigned char  DataOffset[4];
}__attribute__( (packed) );

struct bmpInfoHeader{
    unsigned char Size[4];
    unsigned char Width[4];
    unsigned char Height[4];
    unsigned char Planes[2];
    unsigned char BitsPerPixel[2];
    unsigned char Compression[4];
    unsigned char ImageSize[4];
    unsigned char XpixelsPerM[4];
    unsigned char YpixelsPerM[4];
    unsigned char ColorsUsed[4];
    unsigned char ImportantColors[4];


}__attribute__( (packed) );



int main(void)
{
    uint32_t QR_width = 16; uint32_t QR_height = 16;

    unsigned char palette_data[8] = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xff,0x00};
    uint32_t size = ( ((QR_width*QR_height)/8)+ ( ((QR_width*QR_height) % 8 )? 1 : 0  ) + 54 + sizeof(palette_data));

    struct bmpHeader a;
    struct bmpInfoHeader b;


    unsigned char headerSize = sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) + sizeof(pallete_data);

    printf(" size of struct is %d\n", sizeof(a) + sizeof(b));
    printf(" size of image data in bytes = %d\n", size-54-8);
    printf(" size of file in bytes = %d\n", size);

    a.Signature[0] = 0x42; a.Signature[1] = 0x4d; //'BM'
    a.FileSize[0] = (unsigned char) size;   a.FileSize[1] = (unsigned char) size>>8;    a.FileSize[2] = (unsigned char) size>>16;   a.FileSize[3] = (unsigned char) size>>24;
    a.reserved[0] = 0;  a.reserved[1] = 0;  a.reserved[2] = 0;  a.reserved[3] = 0;
    a.DataOffset[0] = headerSize;   a.DataOffset[1] = headerSize>>8;    a.DataOffset[2] = headerSize>>16;   a.DataOffset[3] = headerSize>>24;
    
    b.Size[0]=40;b.Size[1]=0;b.Size[2]=0;b.Size[3]=0;

    b.Width[0]=QR_width;    b.Width[1]=QR_width >> 8;   b.Width[2]=QR_width >> 16;  b.Width[3]=QR_width >> 24;
    b.Height[0]=QR_height;  b.Height[1]=QR_height>>8;   b.Height[2]=QR_height>>16;  b.Height[3]=QR_height>>24;
    b.Planes[0] = 1; b.Planes[1] = 0;
    b.BitsPerPixel[0] = 1; b.BitsPerPixel[1] = 0;
    b.Compression[0]=0; b.Compression[1]=0; b.Compression[2]=0; b.Compression[3]=0; 
    b.ImageSize[0]=0;   b.ImageSize[1]=0;   b.ImageSize[2]=0;   b.ImageSize[3]=0;   
    
    b.XpixelsPerM[0]=0; b.XpixelsPerM[1]=0; b.XpixelsPerM[2]=0; b.XpixelsPerM[3]=0; 
    b.YpixelsPerM[0]=0; b.YpixelsPerM[1]=0; b.YpixelsPerM[2]=0; b.YpixelsPerM[3]=0; 
    b.ColorsUsed[0]=0;  b.ColorsUsed[1]=0;  b.ColorsUsed[2]=0;  b.ColorsUsed[3]=0;  
    b.ImportantColors[0]=0; b.ImportantColors[1]=0; b.ImportantColors[2]=0; b.ImportantColors[3]=0;

    int i=0;
    char* img = calloc( (QR_width*QR_height)/8, sizeof(unsigned char));
    for(i=0; i<32; i++)
        img[i] = 0xff;


    FILE *fptr = fopen("QRcode.bmp","wb");
    if(fptr != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(&a, sizeof(struct bmpHeader), 1, fptr);
        fwrite(&b, sizeof(struct bmpInfoHeader), 1, fptr);
        fwrite(palette_data, sizeof(palette_data), 1, fptr);
        fwrite(img, 32, 1, fptr);
        fclose(fptr);
    }   

    free(img);


    return 0;
}
```

The expected result a small white bmp image, but I am not getting it correctly. what went wrong here?

Comment: Most likely one or more of your header fields are wrong. Create a bitmap with an app that you know works and compare.

Comment: Please show your code! Thank you.

Comment: @Evg I was thinking low-level programming is the closest thing to manipulate binary files and images. can you recommend me another tag?

Comment: It is unusual to declare the uint32 and uint16 fields of the header as arrays of char, but that's just a style comment - aside from that, try setting `ColorsUsed` to 2 instead of zero.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I did that to make it easier for little endian representation. And I've tried the value 2, no difference.

Comment: I would say, your byte order is wrong. When I look at Filesize attribute it's `0x5e 00 00 00` while it should be `0x00 00 00 5e`. Same for Dataoffset and probably the other fields as well.

Comment: @Devolus I think because bmp file follows the little endian representation, correct?

Comment: Little endian, correct. I think the `DataOffset` should point to where the pixel data actually starts.

Comment: @Devolus the BMP is just a binary dump of some DIB structures as is, so they most definitely are always little-endian because of where Windows originates...

Comment: Yes, I just checked that, it's little endian. The definition doesn't say anything about it. But I fail to see why this structure is done so complicated with unsigned char representation then.

Comment: I would create that image in paint, with the same dimension and color and just compare the hexdumps. Should be easy to see where it differs to find the bug.

Comment: @Devolus You are right, I will make a macro to convert endianness. Thanks :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I have just changed the offset and added more 8 bytes for the palette array. still not working properly.

Comment: Go back and try my first suggestion, then.